# What am I looking for when using Memtest86?

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I was told to download [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com) in order to check to see if RAM has any issues. I am at the main technical page and I’m not really sure what to look for. I have already run the test and it says there are no errors but is there any data that could be useful to finding out if there is an issue?  Step-by-step instructions would be appreciated I am on mobile.

Comment: run it from a DVD/usb flash drive. If you only see blue with white text, the RAM is fine. If you have errors, you see text on red background: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lxyU3.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have already run the test and it says there are no errors but is
>   there any data that could be useful to finding out if there is an
>   issue?

Well, if you ran the tests and there are no issues, then you have no issues and there is nothing more you should do. So congratulations! Your RAM checks out fine.

If you are still concerned there is a RAM issue on your system, the only other thing you could do is run the tests in a series of consecutive cycles/loops over an extended period of time—sometimes even days—to see if such repeated tests reveal any issues. But honestly, I have rarely seen any RAM that was bad not show up immediately in an initial test. So that’s basically the best/most you can do.

And while some people say you will need a fairly long, multi-day “burn in” test to truly check if RAM is good or bad, I think in your case that might not be needed. I say this since you are clearly trying to pinpoint some system irregularity that is so persistent and casually noticeable from low-level normal daily usage point-of-view that a 48-72 hour intense “burn in” test would indeed fail in your case. But that kind of failure would and should happen very early in the testing process; like within a few hours or so; not after a few days.

Comment: Damnit. I was hoping there was an issue haha. God damnit I'm running out of options. Thanks :)

Comment: It ran 4 passes and took about 7 and a half hours.

Comment: When I worked for a system builder we used to urn MemTest86+ for 72 consecutive hours as our minimum.  More than once I saw RAM fail on day 3.